# AutoCompleteText not update popup background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, background, autocompletetextview

I am using `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` but I cannot change the background of the dropdown list or neither the color of the background of the selector. I tried color or drawable but nothing change.

```
     <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/topicEt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/corner_shape_spinner_darkness"
                    android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/support_select_topic"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:paddingStart="12dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Body_12"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/gray200"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/dropdown_icon_selector"
                    android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                    android:dropDownSelector="@color/lightness100"
                    android:popupBackground="@color/darkness100"/>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` selector background with `app:backgroundTint` attribute.

And change the background of the dropdown list programmatically with either:

```
autoCompleteTV.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.RED))
autoCompleteTV.setDropDownBackgroundResource(resourceId) // takes a color/drawable resource
```